# OrientDB 2.1 on Azure

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to use an OrientDB instance on Azure. OrientDB 2.1.4 is installed on an Azure A2 node. In comparison with running OrientDB 2.0 there's a huge performance decrease, in fact it's that huge (slow) that it's actually unusable. Does anyone have similar experiences, or tips how to solve this.
So OrientDB 2.0.12 runs nicely, but once I start using OrientDB 2.1.x it's dead slow.

There appears to be nothing special in the log:

```
2015-10-16 09:08:58:451 INFO  OrientDB auto-config DISKCACHE=939MB (heap=455MB os=3,442MB disk=21,465MB) [orientechnologies]
2015-10-16 09:08:58:659 INFO  Loading configuration from: /home/development/orientdb-community-2.1.4/config/orientdb-server-config.xml... [OServerConfigurationLoaderXml]
2015-10-16 09:08:59:132 INFO  OrientDB Server v2.1.4 (build UNKNOWN@r; 2015-10-13 12:23:58+0000) is starting up... [OServer]
2015-10-16 09:08:59:209 INFO  Databases directory: /home/development/orientdb-community-2.1.4/databases [OServer]
2015-10-16 09:08:59:348 INFO  Listening binary connections on 0.0.0.0:2424 (protocol v.32, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2015-10-16 09:08:59:359 INFO  Listening http connections on 0.0.0.0:2480 (protocol v.10, socket=default) [OServerNetworkListener]
2015-10-16 09:08:59:420 INFO  Installing dynamic plugin 'studio-2.1.zip'... [OServerPluginManager]
2015-10-16 09:08:59:617 INFO  Installing dynamic plugin 'orientdb-lucene-2.1.4-dist.jar'... [OServerPluginManager]
2015-10-16 09:08:59:759 INFO  Lucene index plugin installed and active. Lucene version: LUCENE_47 [OLuceneIndexPlugin]
2015-10-16 09:08:59:824 INFO  Installing GREMLIN language v.2.6.0 - graph.pool.max=50 [OGraphServerHandler]
2015-10-16 09:08:59:824 INFO  [OVariableParser.resolveVariables] Error on resolving property: distributed [orientechnologies]
2015-10-16 09:08:59:832 INFO  Installing Script interpreter. WARN: authenticated clients can execute any kind of code into the server by using the following allowed languages: [sql] [OServerSideScriptInterpreter]
2015-10-16 09:08:59:832 INFO  OrientDB Server v2.1.4 (build UNKNOWN@r; 2015-10-13 12:23:58+0000) is active. [OServer]
2015-10-16 09:09:51:123 INFO  {db=mydb} Creating database plocal:/home/development/orientdb-community-2.1.4/databases/mydb [OServerCommandPostDatabase]
2015-10-16 09:11:32:578 SEVER Internal server error:
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OQueryParsingException: Error on parsing query at position #8: Error on parsing command at position #0: Error on parsing query
Query:  _studio WHERE user.name = 'admin' AND type = 'GraphConfig'
-------------^
--> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Class '_STUDIO' was not found in current database [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
2015-10-16 09:11:32:586 WARNI ->10.101.255.252: Command not found: GET.sqlProfiler/mydb [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
2015-10-16 09:11:33:735 SEVER Internal server error:
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OQueryParsingException: Error on parsing query at position #8: Error on parsing command at position #0: Error on parsing query
Query:  _studio WHERE type = 'Bookmark' ORDER BY name ASC
-------------^
--> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Class '_STUDIO' was not found in current database [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
2015-10-16 09:12:23:079 WARNI ->10.101.255.252: Command not found: GET.sqlProfiler/mydb [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
2015-10-16 09:15:13:344 WARNI ->10.101.255.252: Command not found: GET.sqlProfiler/mydb [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
2015-10-16 09:27:19:432 WARNI ->10.101.255.252: Command not found: GET.sqlProfiler/mydb [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]
2015-10-16 09:28:00:017 INFO  Received signal: SIGINT [OSignalHandler]
2015-10-16 09:28:00:018 INFO  OrientDB Server is shutting down... [OServer]
2015-10-16 09:28:00:019 INFO  Shutting down listeners: [OServer]
2015-10-16 09:28:00:019 INFO  - ONetworkProtocolBinary /0.0.0.0:2424: [OServer]
```

We're running:

```
Linux version 3.16.0-40-generic (buildd@brownie) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #54~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 10 17:30:45 UTC 2015 (Ubuntu 3.16.0-40.54~14.04.1-generic 3.16.7-ckt11)
```

Thanks,

Xander

Comment: Could you please check logs under logs/ folder that don't contain lines at FINE level?

Comment: Nothing special in the log I think, see post edit.

Comment: Do you have some queries  to share that are slower in 2.1.x?

Comment: It's not about optimizing queries, actually all operations are really slow.